# Jumping to a single frame in Node created in Cocos Studio

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a Node named "Fruit" which contains 4 single frames for each fruit. It also contains a shadow, which should be the same for all fruits. I'm creating this node like this:

```
    auto newFruit = CSLoader::createNode("Fruit.csb");
    auto fruitAction = CSLoader::createTimeline("Fruit.csb");
    newFruit->runAction(fruitAction);
```

Now when I'm creating this fruit I want to set a random frame:

```
    fruitAction->gotoFrameAndPause(r + 1);
```

r is from 0 to 3.

However it doesn't work. It doesn't change frame at all. When I run debugging I can see correct frame number.

So I've tried different solution. I've made 4 1-frame animations named "a1", "a2", "a3" and "a4".

Then:

```
    fruitAction->play("a" + to_str(r + 1), false);
```

Now I'm getting sometimes good sometimes not. Giving constant r continuously is giving me different results.

Only solution I've found is to make all animation 2-frames long (with 1 offset) so "a1": 0->1, "a2": 2->3, "a3":4->5, "a4":6->7, but this is too complicated to be worth using. Also it sometimes blinks first frame for a frame or few (so it looks very bad then).

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in cocos2d-x code it seems more troublesome than it looks.

There are 3 problems in current implementation:

1) when you won't play your animation it'll have playing property set to false so ActionTimeline::step won't even pass first if (checking if playing) and it'll never render another frame.

2) when you use gotoFrameAndPause _endFrame is never set (it's 0 by default) and because of that setCurrentFrame will always fail, because of this if:
if (frameIndex >= _startFrame && frameIndex <= _endFrame)

3) when you use "play" _startFrame and _endFrame are set between just this one particular animation and you won't be able to "jump" to frame outside it.

I've made a little workaround and put that in 3 macros:

```
#define CC_INIT_ACTION(__ACTION__) __ACTION__->gotoFrameAndPlay(0, __ACTION__->getDuration() + 1, 0, false); __ACTION__->pause()
#define CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME(__ACTION__, __FRAME__) __ACTION__->setCurrentFrame(__FRAME__); __ACTION__->resume(); __ACTION__->step(0.0001f); __ACTION__->pause()
#define CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME_BY_NAME(__ACTION__, __NAME__) int __FRAME__ = __ACTION__->getAnimationInfo(__NAME__).startIndex; CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME(__ACTION__, __FRAME__)
```

CC_INIT_ACTION makes possible to jump to every frame.
CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME jumps to particular frame number.
CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME_BY_NAME jumps to first frame in particular animation.

Also step(0.0001f) in CC_JUMP_ACTION_TO_FRAME is necessary, because step sometimes calculates current frame wrong (maybe rounding problem, not sure).